# SSRS PMT Function producing #ERROR

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am hoping someone can help me here. I am using the PMT function to calculate mortgage payments in SSRS. I am using the following Formula

```
=IIF(Note = "Present",-PMT(Rate/12,Term,Balance,0,DueDate.EndOfPeriod),Nothing))
```

The formula works perfectly when Note = Present.  However on all other loans it is producing #ERROR. I don't understand why this is happening.

Is there some other error handling that needs to be done to simply leave the cell blank if the note is not present?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with PMT but it could be that the values passed to PMT are invalid for loans where Note is not "Present". If this is the case then I would use a `SWITCH` statement instead. `SWITCH` will stop at the first expression that evaluates to `True`, whereas `IIF` evaluates all expressions, even the expression that does not get used!

try this..

```
=SWITCH(
        Note <> "Present", Nothing,
        True, -PMT(Rate/12,Term,Balance,0,DueDate.EndOfPeriod)
        )
```

This way, if note is not "Present" then return nothing and only if it IS "Present" evaluate the PMT function and return its value. The `True` just acts like an `else` to save us writing `Note = "Present"` for the second condition

Answer (score 1):

SSRS will always evaluate both sides of a conditional expression, no matter what the result of the first parameter boolean test.  This means that

`-PMT(Rate/12,Term,Balance,0,DueDate.EndOfPeriod)`

must be a valid calculation for rows where `Note <> "Present"` as well or you will get an expressions error.  I would suggest that probably some of the other fields aren't populated with appropriate "dummy" values in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

What is Nothing in your code?

```
=IF(Note = "Present",-PMT(Rate/12,Term,Balance,0,DueDate.EndOfPeriod),0))
```

Comment: Nothing just means I want an empty result or null result.  I have tried your suggestion of 0 and still produces #ERROR